# BigQuery SQL: Identify records after n days recursively

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When working on the implementation of an easier business logic, I asked myself what would I do if the business requirements looked like the following:

**Business Requirement**

Let's say there is a customer id and a visit timestamp in a table. Now business wants to send a special promotion to the customer after their very first visit and at each first visit after at least n days (let's set 7 for n for this example) since the customer qualified for their last promotion.

**Example Data**

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
| row_no | customer_id |         visit_ts          |
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
|      1 | A           | 2020-01-01 07:00:00.00000 |
|      2 | A           | 2020-01-01 09:00:00.00000 |
|      3 | A           | 2020-01-02 17:00:00.00000 |
|      4 | A           | 2020-01-08 20:00:00.00000 |
|      5 | A           | 2020-01-11 11:30:00.00000 |
|      6 | A           | 2020-01-16 08:00:00.00000 |
|      7 | B           | 2020-01-11 10:00:00.00000 |
|      8 | B           | 2020-01-16 10:00:00.00000 |
|      9 | B           | 2020-01-18 11:00:00.00000 |
|     10 | B           | 2020-01-20 11:00:00.00000 |
|     11 | B           | 2020-01-27 09:00:00.00000 |
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

**Desired Result**

Customer A: row_no 1,4,6

Customer B: row_no 7,9,11

**What I tried so far**

It's pretty straight forward to find previous visit_ts for each record using LAG function or window framing. In the next step, we can calculate the diff between visit_ts and prev_visit_ts with the help of [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) function, which gives us the number of seconds between these two timestamps.

Finally, we can calculate a running sum on this value by using window function once more:

```
SELECT *, 
   # Step 3: Calc running sum of seconds since last visit - how to reset after reaching a threshold?
  SUM(sec_since_last_visit) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY visit_ts ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as running_sum
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    # Step 2: Calc the amount of seconds between this and prev visit
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(visit_ts,prev_visit_ts,SECOND) AS sec_since_last_visit
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      # Step 1: Calc visit_ts of previous visit
      LAG(visit_ts) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY visit_ts) AS prev_visit_ts
    FROM
      table ) )
```

**What does not work?**

What I cannot find a solution for: I need to somehow reset the running sum once it reached the threshold of 7 days. There is no [RESET WHEN](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/M7v51PbSWhLf0by764_hiA) clause in BigQuery like there is in Teradata. Nor can one nest analytical functions or use recursion in BigQuery for that. The option of using a logical [RANGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_window_frame) around the current row does only allow for static values which doesn't help either, I guess.

Is there actually a way of solving this in BigQuery (w/o using Stored Procedures)?

Of course, this problem can be solved pretty easily using an iterative or recursive approach in a programming language like python or java. However, I am specifically interested in whether there is a way of solving this problem in BigQuery Standard SQL and how this solution looks like.

Comment: This requires looping.  In standard SQL, you can do it using a recursive CTE.  BigQuery now supports scripting, which can be used.  I don't think you can do this in a single query, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks! By standard SQL you mean outside BigQuery, right? At this point, BigQuery does not seem to support any form of recursive queries, does it? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause .

Comment: . . . I would refer to it as "ANSI Standard SQL", but I think it is now ISO Standard.  That is different from BQ StandardSQL.

Comment: you're right here -  guess the term  "Standard SQL" that  BQ uses is a bit misleading as it kind of suggests it's ANSI standard.

Comment: can yo please elaborate more around `The option of using a logical RANGE around the current row does only allow for static values which doesn't help either`? not sure what you mean by `static values`. what is that yo need to be dynamic here? please explain more your logic